# How to resolve php version 5.4 in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi Recently I have updated my PHP version from 5.0 to 5.4,but it creates error in my CakePHP projects because it was running on older version of PHP the error are

> Fatal Error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

It is common error error displaying on every projects how to remove this please help.thanks

Comment: Did you used short tag ? Like <?

Comment: @AlimonKarim yes i used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open you short_open tag in your php.ini file

```
 short_open_tag=Off
```

To

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Comment: The correct solution is the other way around: _don't_ use short open tags.